# What does "Nuke" in DotNetNuke mean?

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke

A co-worker asked me how the word "Nuke" relates to CMS? To be honest I never thought about it, and there wasn't any information on the web that I could find.

Francisco Burzi wrote that his Perl script that he used to manage content was called NUKE. His knowledge of that system fueled his adaptation of thatware to phpNuke.

Does anyone know what NUKE stands for and how it is related to content management?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the term Nuke originates with phpNuke and subsequent forks such as PostNuke. dotnetNuke just adopted the term from the php version.

I have no clue why phpNuke was named as such, but google to the rescue!

http://74.125.95.132/search?q=cache:atpksHABV2AJ:www.uiarch.org/CMpro-v-p-36.htm+origins+of+name+NUKE+cms&hl=en&ct=clnk&cd=10&gl=us

in short, "The name was taken from Francisco's user name of Nuke from the days when he was a cracker"

Answer (score 2):

From the faq (http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Knowledge/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/tabid/546/Default.aspx)

> "The new name was chosen to reflect
>   the applications .NET (DOTNET)
>   framework, and coupled with the term
>   “nuke” (due to *nuke’s inherent,
>   industry-recognized inclusion in
>   several existing open source portal
>   initiatives.)"

Comment: well, I cancelled my downvote (oooh peer pressure! :> ) but the question asked about "nuke" in relation to CMSes, and specifically mentions the creator of phpNuke, the original. This answer begs the question.

Answer (score 0):

Microwave ovens produce **junk** food. So he choose **phpnuke** because the other choice had been **junkphp**?

Crazy :-)

Answer (score -1):

I'd heard that it relates to the slang term for using a microwave oven.  Using a CMS adds convenience to updating a web site in a similar way that using a microwave is so much faster and simpler than using a real oven.  But that's just hearsay.